# Get packet loss from Open Flow switch

Tags: packet-loss, openflow, mininet, sdn

I am using an Ryu controller (3.22) to monitor switches (Open vSwitch 2.0.2, supporting Open Flow 1.3), which are a part of virtual network created using mininet (2.1.0). It is a tree topology with depth = 2 and fanout = 5. I am using [switch_monitor.py](https://github.com/osrg/ryu-book/blob/master/en/source/sources/simple_monitor.py)

With the help of the controller, I can get port statistics using the `EventOFPPortStatsReply` decorator. I can get values of `rx_packets`, `rx_bytes`, `rx_errors`, `tx_packets`, `tx_bytes`, `tx_errors`, `rx_dropped`, `tx_dropped` etc., but the values of `rx_dropped`, `tx_dropped` always come out to be **zero**, even when the switches are actually dropping packets, as reported by qdisc (linux command).

**How do I get packet loss statistics from an Open Flow switch?**

1. **How to get a non zero value?**
2. **Is there any alternate way?**

Comment: What packet loss do you want to measure? How many packets are dropped due to rules? Then use ovs-ofctl dump-flows bridgename.

Comment: Packet loss due to queue full

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

qdisc reports what the *kernel* is dropping, not what the *network* is dropping. You're getting zero's because the switch isn't dropping frames.

(I don't know if your virtual network system supports simulating frame drops.)